# How to minimize disk queue in the server?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2005, database-performance

On my database server the disk queue is always at 100%. I am using SQL server 2005. And it has 4GB RAM memory. Please suggest to me how to reduce the disk queue.

Comment: Use indexes, and efficient queries. Possibly upgrade your hardware?

Comment: @MarkW My DB server have Windows XP OS with Service pack 2 and 4 GB RAM. If I upgrade RAM size to 8 GB, will that make any refletion in reducing disk queue?

Comment: I doubt that increasing your RAM would help with a disk queue problem. Bruce Adamczak responded to an inquiry about disk queue length and what it means, and some approaches to improving your numbers here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dfa96ef4-6fe1-460a-9407-e2d714a776ba/need-help-on-explanation-of-avg-disk-queue-length?forum=perfmon I think it means, the hard drive latency is high, resulting in requests filling the queue. Like I mentioned before, you can decrease your disk usage by making effective use of indexes, studying execution plans, and hardware.

Comment: Also, just as a note, Current Disk Queue Length, and Avg. Disk Write Queue Length are not percentages in perfmon. You can increase the scale of the graph to see the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was caused by a query in UPDATE trigger on one of the main tables in the database. The query was inserting into the log tables from temp DELETED table. We changed the query to use INSERTED table and it solved the problem.